# How To Skip Silence in Audio In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio

I have searched a lot about this but I can't find any solid code snippet of anything like that that explains how this would work.

Google Podcasts web app does this and I would like to learn how this works for a web app I'm building.

A lot of podcast apps let you skip silences even as small as half a second long silences.

How can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want to just skip the silence or do you want to identify where in the audio the silence occurs so that you can skip it?

Comment: I would like my audio player to skip silences wherever they might be. Any silence longer than a second should be automatically skipped like Google Podcasts web app does. :)

Comment: _"How can I do this with..."_ You need to decode the incoming audio into PCM format (raw audio values). These numbers are the **amplitude** of each audio sample (_eg:_ 44100 samples for CD quality). Research about [decodeAudioData](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/webaudio/AudioContext/decodeAudioData/). Ideally you want to stick to loading (into an Array/Buffer) a specific format like MP3 (not just "audio"), because from there you can slice the mp3 at each frame header (or get enough frames to make one second, so you are slicing by each second). Decode to PCM and check for zeroes...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Skip Silence in Video</title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="videoPlayer" controls></video>
<script>
function skipSilence() {
  const video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const outputChunks = [];

  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
    canvas.width = videoWidth;
    canvas.height = videoHeight;
  });
  video.addEventListener('play', () => {
    const fps = 30; // Adjust the desired frame rate
    setInterval(() => {
      if (video.paused || video.ended) return;
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      const frameData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
       // Check if the frame contains silence (all black pixels)
      const isSilent = frameData.every((value, index) => {
        return index % 4 !== 3 || value === 0;
      });
      if (!isSilent) {
        outputChunks.push(canvas.toDataURL());
      }
    }, 1000 / fps);
  });
  video.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    const outputVideo = document.createElement('video');
    outputVideo.controls = true;
    outputChunks.forEach((chunk) => {
      const source = document.createElement('source');
      source.src = chunk;
      outputVideo.appendChild(source);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(outputVideo);
  });
   // Specify the path to your video file
  video.src = 'G:/Fking/LECTURS/chemmmmm/test.mp4';
  video.load();
  video.play();
}
     // Call the function to skip silence in the video
    skipSilence();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Something like this maybe ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer.